# android- url does not open android app

Tags: android

I want to open my application if the url is clicked .I made this href :

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here" >open app</a>
```

in the manifest I did this :

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.tejarat.example.Urlchema"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

the problem is from url ,When I click on it , it says not found and nothing happens .

Could you help me ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code of "Urlchema" Activity ?

Comment: @Swayam I put a log on the first line , it is not comming in ,it shows me 404 on the webpage

Comment: Problem is  in scheme name. You can not use "."(dot) in scheme. Review my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this it will work

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's work for me

```
<a href='demo://www.abc.com/'>demo://www.abc.com/</a></body></html>
```

in the manifest

```
  <activity android:name=".myActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:scheme="demo"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```